# how to include files in node js and execute function within them

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files and I want to include all the function in file2 which must be executed on the script load, I tried it with module exports, but when the file2 executes it does not update the variable "kList" in file 1

I will be including all the functions in file two which will update variables in file 1

File1:-

```
var kList=[];
var exlist=require("./file2.js");
exlist.lister()

setInterval(function(){
console.log(kList);},3000)
```

File2:-

```
var request= require('requests');
function lister(){
request.get("www.example.com",function(err,response,body){
body.forEach(body=>{
kList.push(body.item)
});
});
}
module.exports.lister=lister;
```

Comment: use  `require()` function

Comment: @niklaz I tried with it but it does not update the variable in file1

Comment: The wording of your question implies that you expect the file to be **edited** and now just the variable that it causes to be loaded into memory to be changed. Is that the case? You also have no code which would inspect the value of the variable, so how can you tell that it isn't being updated? You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin I've updated the code

Comment: @Smitk — You said you were using `require`. I don't need that in your code. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin Edited again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Code in one module does not have access to variables in another module.

For your `lister` function to have access to the array you assign to `klist`, you need to pass it as an argument.

```
exlist.lister(klist);
```

and

```
function lister(klist) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS you cannot access a variable from another module.

If you need to set a value you should write your module in a way that it return or acquire the variable you need to change.

for example, you can rewrite your module 2 to accept a variable:

```
module.exports = function (kList) {
    request("www.example.com",function(err,response,body){
        body.forEach(body=>{
            kList.push(body.item)
        })
    })
}
```

In module 1:

```
const module2 = require('./module2');

var kList = [];
moduel2(kList);
```

The better way is to let the *module2* return the value, as it is an async function you should pass the *callback* function from *module1*.

```
// module 2
module.exports = function (callback) {
    request(url, callback);
}
```

You can also preprocess the data and pass just the result:

```
module.exports = function (callback) {
    request(url, function () {
        var data = [];
        body.forEach(/* process the data*/);
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

A cleaner way is to *promisify* the module:

```
// module 2
module.exports = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function (err,response,body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }

            resolve(body.item);
        });
    });
}
```

So in your *module1* you can just get the result of the promise:

```
// module 1
var kList=[];

const module2 = require('./module2');

module2().then(items => (kList = items.reduce(/* ... */))
         .catch(error => (/* handle the error here*/));
```

As it is a promise you can just chain as many layers you want, in *module2* or *module1* as you need, just remember to return something from the *then()*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing kList in the argument

```
File1:
var kList = [];
var exlist = require('./file2');
exlist.lister(kList)
setInterval(function () {
console.log(kList);
}, 3000)

File2:
function lister(kList) {
body = [1,2,3,4]
body.forEach(item => {
    kList.push(item)
});
}
module.exports.lister = lister;
```